# How many two-page spreads (160gsm A4 paper) should be bound together in one signature?

Tags: paper, book-binding

I'm binding a sketch book as a birthday present. This is my first experience in book-binding. I've bought 16 A4 sheets of 160g/m<sup>2</sup> black paper and I wonder how big should be one signature of sheets. I was planning to bind four pages in one, so the book will consist of 4 signatures of 4 sheets each, but they may be too thick to be folded after binding in such bundles. So should I do 8 signatures of 2 sheets instead? Or maybe I just have to fold or bind them a bit differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Normal" signatures are often 4 pages, but with 160grams paper, I prefer signatures of 2 since it makes the book lay more flat. It also helps to make a very sharp fold.

Comment: Thank you, I agree. I've already made a book with 2 page signatures and it turned out great.

Comment: @GlebSabirzyanov Nice! You can accept this answer if it helped you, so others can use if if they have the same problem.